# Implementing error prevention with array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Im developing a commenting system that a reporter inputs the name of the home team and away team then clicks a button to send them to the reporters feed. However i want to implement error prevention as I only want the English Premier League teams. 
An array is used to contain the team names. Is it possible to stop a login happening after the button is pressed to login if the input team names do not match values from the array?

Code as follows:

```
var teamNames = new Array();
```

HTML:

```
    <input id="txtHomeTeam" type="text" class="textBox" value="Home Team" />
    <input id="txtAwayTeam" type="text" class="textBox" value="Away Team" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Is there a question here? I don't see it.

Comment: In general, if you want to restrict users to select from a limit set of options, *don't use a textbox*. Use a drop-down or some other appropriate control. Using a textbox will just cause both you and your users headaches.

Comment: Sorry, the error message keeps popping up saying no name has been entered. I was wondering how to fix this. Basically the alert keeps popping up saying enter a team name anytime i press the button to log in

Comment: You problem is in your loop logic. First time through the loop, it will check if *both* home and away team is `arsenal` and then throw up the error message if it's not. You need to check if *either* team is `arsenal` and then flag that you've validated either the home or away team, then continue through the loop until you have either validated both teams, or the end of the loop is reached. If you reach the end and one or both teams haven't been validated, then you throw your error. Bonus points: check the home != away. A team can't play itself!

Comment: double bonus points: use .`tolower()` on the users input because `"Arsenal" != "arsenal"`

Comment: Thanks man! I will have a crack at this. Gonna do home != away after the rest works!

Answer (score 0):

Your loop logic is all wrong, as I stated in my comments, but searching through the array by looping is a waste when you can just use [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) instead.

Something like:

```
var homeTeam = $("#txtHomeTeam").val().toLower();
var awayTeam = $("#txtAwayTeam").val().toLower();

if (homeTeam != awayTeam) {
    if (teamNames.indexOf(homeTeam) >= 0 && teamNames.indexOf(awayTeam) >= 0) {
        // now we know both teams are valid
    }
    else {
        // unknown team
    }
}
else {
    // a team can't play itself!!!
}
```

However, I also still stand by my comment that using a free text box and expecting a user to only enter a limited set of values is bad UI. Use a drop-down or similar selector to avoid frustrating users with typos like `Arsenel` or people typing just `Hull` instead of `Hull City` or worse `Hull Tigers`!

Comment: Yeah you're right with the drop-down I hadn't even thought about it. However I needed it implemented quick and I had already started this way so thought I best finish it. If i get time after finishing the rest I will definitely implement a drop down. Thanks you've been a great help!